# Can I make my MySQL online not on local but world wide

Tags: mysql

I work using command line and wanna know that gow can I access my MySQL databases from another pc on a different network.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access it from outside the network with correct permissions.  Or since you are using CLI you can remote in and access it that way

Comment: Thanks buddy but can u explain me CLI

Comment: CLI is just another term for Command Line (I = Interface)   If you are using Linux I suggest a program like putty to connect across PC's

Comment: Ok I got it but still can u say me an example of any such command

Answer (score 0):

You need to config MySQL to listen on your computer address with proper port.
  Edit `my.cnf` file with command `bind-address`

```
bind-address xx.xx.xx.xx
```

`xx.xx.xx.xx` is your ip address

Comment: Couldn't find bind-address xx.xx.xx.xx in my.cnf

Comment: @Harshit Sengar - Needless to say, opening MySQL DB like this if you don't know what you're doing is a recipe for a disaster.